# Eclipse project creation error

Tags: ros, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got eclipse kepler installed and it seems to work fine. However I went to create an eclipse project for a package and got this error:

```
rosbox@rosbox-VirtualBox:~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials$ make eclipse-project

`make: *** No rule to make target `eclipse-project'.  Stop.
```

I'm using ROS groovy on ubuntu 12.04. I tried looking around this thread: http://answers.ros.org/question/11367/problem-integrating-ros-with-eclipse-indigo/ but I didn't really find anything that worked. They were talking about the cmake files in one of the comments but I didn't quite follow what they were talking about.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71971/eclipse-project-creation-error/) by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 124 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

make eclipse-project does not work anymore with catkin.

Use this instead:

```
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

See: http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-08-09**:
I'm getting a little confused here. The article keeps referring to "the MakeFile" that needs to have an include edited in. Is it referring to each individual makefile for each project under catkin_ws/build, or is it talking about the main one in catkin_ws/build?

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-08-09**:
So I tried running the command. The article says the project files should end up under catkin_ws/build. I found one entry: Project@build in that location. It seems however to just contain all the files in that directory and none of the code from catkin_ws/src. Is this correct?

**Comment by [AlphaSierra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4924/alphasierra/) on 2013-08-10**:
I got it. I found the source directory link, guess I just kept missing it. This thread finally clued me in:
http://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!